# Side navigation submenu flyout pushes down other menu items in IE7

Tags: css, internet-explorer

This problem is only showing up in IE7. Other browsers and IE8 and above work fine.

I am using a sprite map with an `ul` for my side navigation. There is a fly-out submenu for one of the `li` elements which also uses a sprite map with an `ul` for downloading various PDFs.

If you look at the image that I've attached, the submenu is appearing in the correct location, but it's pushing down everything below it. (The word "Music" should appear directly below the word "Menu".)

I have tried various fixes using a `display: inline;` element and `position: static;` element, but my attempts have failed. Would really appreciate some help on this. The website address is: http://www.graysonmain.com/

[image: screen grab of IE7 screwing up my navigation]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a fixed height, `height: 58px` and `display: inline-block` for `li#nav_02`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into overlays with CSS?  I'm very new to this so I, personally, can't give you a concrete answer, but it might be possible to set the positioning of the submenus and toggle the visibility with an onClick() command.